# Django Djoser авторизация и регистрация

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Всем привет. Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

В проекте авторизация пользователя должна работать через email и password.

В настройках Джанго есть такой код:

```
DJOSER = {
    'HIDE_USERS': False,
    'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
    'PERMISSIONS': {
        'user_list': [
            'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'
        ],
    },
}
```

Суть такова, когда настройка 'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email' активна, то регистрация не работает.
`create_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'`
Авторизация да, работает. Но как правильно сделать регистрацию - не понятно. В документации тоже ничего не нашел, может плохо искал. Подскажите, как правильно сделать регистрацию и авторизацию через Djoser с помощью полей email и пароль?

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено. Надо в модели юзера, созданной на основе абстрактного, создать поле username

```
username = models.CharField(
    blank=True, 
    max_length=150,
)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

Из настроек убрал параметр

```
'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
```

И добавить доп. параметры. После этого все заработало.